# Graphic style keep erasing

Tags: adobe-illustrator

I create my design using appearance panel. Then alt click 'new graphic style', named it and instantaneously it appears in graphic style panel.

But each time i create a new document it disappears.
It seems like nothing was saved!

I see tutorials and all do this far. but theirs graphic style is not keep disappearing.

Am i missing something?

Comment: Graphic styles are file dependent. So unless you overwrite the default template file then yes the style will get reset when you make a new file.

Comment: how can i overwrite it?? please tell me

Comment: Save over it the file. You can find the files in illustrator preference folders. If you dont know where that is consult your manual for whatever version os combo you are using

Comment: [Adobe: Illustrator Graphic Styles help](https://helpx.adobe.com/illustrator/using/graphic-styles.html) <-- Scroll down to the bottom of that page.

Comment: okay. Thankyou :)